# Does this sound right? "We don't have a Beta fleet at present"

Tags: word-order, synonyms

> *We don't have a Beta fleet at present*.

In this sentence, should *at present* be at the beginning? Should *at present* be used at all?

I'm trying to say that right now we don't have it or support it, but we might have it later.

Comment: I think "at present" is a good way to subtly indicate that something is not available now, although it may be in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At present" can be included at the beginning or the end of the sentence with no difference in meaning -- assuming the sentence isn't complicated enough that moving it would make it appear to refer to a different thing.

> At present, we don't have a Beta fleet.
>
> We don't have a Beta fleet at present.

Both fine.

That said, what is a "Beta fleet"? A "fleet" is a group of vehicles, usually ships but also used for aircraft, trucks, etc. "Beta" is the second letter of the Greek alphabet and is often used in English to designate the second level of something, like, "We do our alpha testing with our own employees and then we ask clients to do beta testing before we release a new product". I don't know any well-recognized meaning for the phrase "beta fleet".